# UseState bug in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm starting with React and I need to use the 'useState()' function in a site.

First, I'm creating the useState variable:
`const [messages, setMessages] = useState(['1111', '222'])`

Then I'm returning a div with the messages.

Up to here it's working, but I have to use my 'SetMessages' command:

`setMessages(...messages, '333')`

And when I write it , my site it stops working and all I see is a white page. I've seen many videos about it and I literraly copied pasted their codes them and it still didn't work, what's wrong with my code and how to use this second command from 'useState' right?

Comment: You're spreading multiple separate arguments to the state setter, did you intend to create a new array?

Comment: Something similar to an array (a small one), there are other ways to do it but now I'm really 
curious about this 'useState'...

Answer (score 1):

When using the spread operator (...) you still need to to wrap that in an object or an array. So [...x, y] or {...x, y}.

In your case

```
setMessages([...messages, '333'])
```

Comment: Tried it and didn't work either :(

Comment: @GabrielSouza that's the issue in your question. If there are more issues in your code, we can't help without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
setMessages(prevMsgs=>[...prevMsgs,"333"])
```